See blank screen when I open iphone simulator
I'm using storyboards to show a view controller. When I open the app, I see a blank white screen. Here's my code
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    private let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    private let settingsOptions = ["Privacy Policy", "Terms of Use", "Support", "Delete Account", "Logout"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        title = "Settings"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SettingsCell")
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settingsOptions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SettingsCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = settingsOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let selectedOption = settingsOptions[indexPath.row]
        switch selectedOption {
        case "Privacy Policy":
            openURL("https://example.com/privacy")
        case "Terms of Use":
            openURL("https://example.com/terms")
        case "Support":
            openURL("https://example.com/support")
        case "Delete Account":
            confirmDeleteAccount()
        case "Logout":
            logoutUser()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helper Functions
    
    private func openURL(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    
    private func confirmDeleteAccount() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Account",
                                      message: "Are you sure you want to delete your account? This action cannot be undone.",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
            self.deleteAccount()
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    private func deleteAccount() {
        // Add your delete account logic here
        print("Account deleted")
    }
    
    private func logoutUser() {
        // Add your logout logic here
        print("User logged out")
    }
}

I set the view controller to be the initial view controller in story board.
Does anyone know why I'm seeing a blank white screen? I checked the other answers on this topic and they didn't help!

Shows the tableview with the 5 rows for me when I create a new iOS project and paste your code in, then set the SettingsViewController class name on the ViewController scene within the storyboard. I might suggest double checking that you've changed the class name to your custom SettingsViewController in the storyboard. If the doesn't work, you may want to investigate using Debug View Hierarchy: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-in-the-appearance-of-your-running-app#Resolve-issues-in-the-layout-of-your-UIKit-and-SwiftUI-views
